Substitute the CSP nonce value in Angular index.html using Apache mod_cspnonce?
I tried to setup CSP nonce in angular application hosted on apache server using mod_cspnonce module.
I was able to construct the below policy and could see the response headers holds correct nonce- value.
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e'"

¿But, how can I substitute or setup the same nonce in index.html?.
<app ngCspNonce="CSP_NONCE"></app>

Any suggestions would be helpful!
